# Selenium assert has class

Tags: html, testing, selenium-ide

I have an element with a known id. I want to assert or verify that it has a specific class.

The HTML of the element is:

```
<a id="SearchList" class="something-else disabled"></a>
```

I want to use the id "SearchList" to locate the element and then verify that it has the class "disabled".

EDITS:

- I am using the Selenium IDE a FireFox addon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
verifyElementPresent | css=a[id='SearchList'][class*='disabled'] |
```

Comment: doesn't the IDE support `css=#SearchList.disabled` ?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't help you for the IED, but in C# I can do this using the GetAttribute method.

```
var allClasses = webElement.GetAttribute("class");
var elementHasClass = allClasses.Split(' ').Any(c => string.Equals("classLookingFor", c, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: @MatthijsWessels yep, that is redundant. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

You could use getAttribute() method to get the attribute and verify that. I assume you use Java for your scripts.

```
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.id("SearchList"));
String disabled = list.getAttribute("disabled");

if(disabled.equals("disabled")){
  // something
}else{
  // something else
}
```

Comment: I am using the Selenium IDE for FireFox.

Comment: The question was not if the element has the attribute "disabled" set, it was about whether the element has the class "disabled"

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for necroposting. I have some addition to what @Purus suggested.

As "disabled" is part of a class name `class="something-else disabled"`, `list.getAttribute("disabled")` will return `null`. My suggestion to do it in the following way (Selenium WebDriver Java client):

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("SearchList"));
String elementClass= element.getAttribute("class");

if(elementClass != null && elementClass.contains("disabled")){
  // something
}else{
  // something else
}
```

Comment: this would pass with class="not-disabled". Just port Aligned's solution to Java if you want java.

Comment: Yes, it would pass "not-disabled", but TS asked to locate concrete class that is "disabled" and not "not-disabled".

Comment: Let me reword: he wants to verify if the element has the class "disabled". If the element has any class that contains the text "disabled" (e.g. "not-disabled"), your code would act as if it has the class "disabled". This is wrong.